# Label quartile / quantile data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data

I searched for a WL implementation of the Python Pandas [qcut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.qcut.html) function but could not find one. Anyone aware of an implementation?

For the moment I just need quartiles and the assignment of values in each quartile to specified labels. I came up with the following two ways to implement it.

```
SeedRandom[314];
data = RandomReal[50, 20];
labels = {a, b, c, d};
```

**Method 1**

Use `BinLists` to bin the data according to the quartile ranges. Create an association that maps values to labels.

```
quartileLabel1[data_, labels_] := Module[{bins, binned, map},
  bins = {-Infinity, Quartiles[data], Infinity} // Flatten;
  binned = BinLists[data, {bins}];
  map = Merge[AssociationThread[First[#], Last[#]] & /@ Transpose[{binned, labels}], First];
  map /@ data
  ]

quartileLabel1[data, labels]
(* {d, c, b, a, a, b, a, c, d, d, b, a, b, c, d, d, c, b, a, c} *)
```

**Method 2**

Use the quartiles to generate arguments for `Which`, call it from a function and map that function over the data.

```
quartileLabel2[data_, labels_] := Module[{quartiles, binLabels, mapper},
  quartiles = Quartiles[data];
  binLabels = Transpose[{quartiles, Most[labels]}];
  mapper[x_] = 
   Which[Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Flatten[{x <= First[#], Last[#]} & /@ binLabels // Append[{True, Last[labels]}]]]];
  mapper /@ data
  ]

quartileLabel2[data, labels]
(* {d, c, b, a, a, b, a, c, d, d, b, a, b, c, d, d, c, b, a, c} *)
```

Any ideas for a better / simpler way to implement this?

Comment: `data /. MapThread[Alternatives @@ # -> #2 &, {binList, labels}]` where `binList` is the `BinLists` result is a different way to write the first solution (but may not be as performant). I think  `BinLists` is the way to go here, that way you're using the appropriate algorithm for binning the values.

Comment: @C.E. I did consider using replacement rules but, as you pointed out, I was concerned about performance. The lists I am working with have ~10K distinct elements and that is a lot of rules. However, your suggestion did provide a cleaner way to generate the map. `map = Merge[MapThread[
  AssociationThread[# -> #2] &, {binned, labels}], First]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Module[{q = Quartiles[#], d= #, l = #2}, 
   l[[1 + Total[Developer`ToPackedArray[UnitStep[# - q & /@ d]], {2}]]]] &;
```

This gives the same output as `quartileLabel1` and `quartileLabel2`:

```
f0[data, labels] == quartileLabel1[data, labels] == quartileLabel2[data, labels]
```

> True

Timing comparisons with `quartileLabel1`and `quartileLabel2`:

```
SeedRandom[314];
dt = RandomReal[50, #] & /@ {1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000};

Table[First[RepeatedTiming[rf0[j] = f0[dt[[j]], labels]]], {j, 1, 4}]
```

> {0.00032, 0.0023, 0.025, 0.262}

```
Table[First[RepeatedTiming[rql1[j] = quartileLabel1[dt[[j]], labels]]], {j, 1,  4}]
```

> {0.0023, 0.023, 0.4, 5.3}

```
Table[First[RepeatedTiming[rql2[j] = quartileLabel2[dt[[j]], labels]]], {j, 1,  4}]
```

> {0.0033, 0.02, 0.144, 1.404}

```
And @@ (rf0[#] == rql1[#] == rql2[#] & /@ Range[4])
```

> True

Comment: Not in my wildest dreams would I have come up with this solution. Very impressive. Thank you!

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and kind words.